# Multiple `interactive` options

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have written a small function to reverse the items in the marked region using the comma as item separator. The function code is:

```lisp
(defun reverse-list (beg end)
  "Reverses a list in-place, where comma ',' is the list item separator."
  (interactive "r")
  (if (region-active-p)
    (let ((region-list (reverse (split-string (region-as-string) ","))))
      (kill-region beg end)
      (loop for s in region-list do (progn
                                      (insert (chomp s))
                                      (insert ", ")))
      (delete-char -2))
    (message "Error: No region selected!")))
```

where `chomp` strips leading/trailing whitespace from a string and `region-as-string` yields the region as a string.

The function is very useful, however it would be great to be able to select the separator on the fly. The behaviour I'm looking for is:

- if called without universal argument use the comma as item separator
- if called with universal argument (`C-u`) ask the user to input a (possibly multi-char) separator string

I tried to achieve this, but haven't been successful in doing so. It would be great if you could provide help!

Thanks in advance,
elemakil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [interactive code](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html) `P` to read the ["raw" prefix argument](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html#Prefix-Command-Arguments). This is `nil` if there was no prefix argument, and non-`nil` if there was a prefix argument, so you can test this and decide whether to set the separator to `","` or to use `read-string` to prompt the user to enter it.

Also, I'd make the following comments on your code:

1. Your function only works if called interactively, so that `beg` and `end` are really the beginning and end of the region. If called non-interactively, these might not match (or there might not even be a region) and in that case your function will go wrong (because it deletes the buffer between `beg` and `end` but inserts the reversal of the region). So you need to call `(buffer-substring beg end)`, not `(region-as-string)`.
2. [Edited, see comments] It's not a good idea to raise an error in the case where the region is inactive. In Emacs, the region continues to *exist* even when it's *inactive* (that is, no longer highlighted). Or the user might have turned off `transient-mark-mode` and so never have an active region at all. In both cases, the user might still want to run your command.

   At most, you might *change the behavior* of the command when the region is active (see for example, [`comment-dwim`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Comment-Commands.html)).
3. You delete the region by calling `kill-region`, which copies the removed text to the kill-ring. Is this really what you want to do? It might surprise the user. It's better to call `delete-region` unless you actually mean to save the deleted text.
4. You don't ensure that point is in the right place before you start calling `insert`. In interactive use, you'll get away with it, but for non-interactive use point could be anywhere, so you ought to move it explicitly. And also use `save-excursion`, of course.
5. It seems very inelegant to insert an extra `", "` and then have to delete it afterwards. Better not to insert it in the first place.

Here's some revised code that fixes all of the above:

```
(defun reverse-list (beg end read-separator)
  "Reverse the region in-place, treating it as a list of items
separated by commas. With a prefix argument, prompt for the
separator."
  (interactive "r\nP")
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((separator (if read-separator (read-string "Separator: ") ","))
           (region-list (nreverse (split-string (buffer-substring beg end) separator)))
           (separator (concat separator " ")))
      (goto-char beg)
      (delete-region beg end)
      (loop for s in region-list
            for sep = "" then separator
            do (insert sep) (insert (chomp s))))))
```

Comment: Indeed a much better solution! Thanks for the detailed commentary, I'm learning elisp and thus this is **very** helpful! One comment though: initially I didn't use the manual error message but then no error occured at all. Also when I use your function without an active region the content of the current line up to `point` is reversed... Maybe this is a bug in my emacs config? When adding my error handling code your function works perfectly.

Comment: In Emacs, the region continues to *exist* even if it's not currently *active* (i.e., highlighted). See "[Mark](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mark.html)" in the manual. It's generally best to write commands so that they operate on the region even if it's not currently active. After all, the user might have turned off `transient-mark-mode` but still want to use your command.

Comment: +1, nice refactoring. Two minor nits: 1. `nreverse` would be preferable to `reverse`, since `split-string` returns a fresh list, so copying it is unnecessary. 2. The `loop` macro's `do` clause already wraps subsequent forms in an implicit `progn`, so the `progn` is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

```
r -- Region: point and mark as 2 numeric args, smallest first.  Does no I/O.
```

Because `r` is always the first two argument. If you use <kbd>C-u</kbd> to pass arguments. Then you may need to pass the argument to the third argument as separator. But you can not pass the third argument without the first and second argument. (I am not sure here. I am a beginner too)

I purpose you to use a `r` and a `s` option to achieve it. Though you always need to provide the separator argument.

Example:

```
(defun reverse-list (beg end &optional sepeartor )
  (interactive "r
ssepeartor:")
  (princ beg)
  (princ "*")
  (princ end)
  (princ sepeartor))
```